# "Secondary" vs "Slave" in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to clarify the terminology difference, if any, between ["Secondary"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-secondary) and ["Slave"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-slave) in mongodb.

Confusion stems from connecting w/ the node-mongodb-native documentation of the [Db constructor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/db.html):

```
db_opts = {db: {
   readPreference: ReadPreference.SECONDARY
   slaveOk: true 
}}

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://example', db_opts, ...)
```

What is the difference between the readPreference option and the slaveOk option there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't get caught up on Secondary vs. Slave here. What you're really asking is about slaveOk vs readPreference.

`slaveOk` is essentially deprecated in favor of using `readPreference`. The [MongoClient docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) do explicitly state for slaveOk: "legacy option allowing reads from secondary, use readPrefrence instead". They also state that setting a readPreference overrides any slaveOk value.